# "Oh, I am not a TV reporter" - why not "I am not the TV reporter" or "I am not TV reporter"?

Tags: articles

Why here they said "a" TV reporter" not "the" or even zero " TV reporter",
Then she replied "a radio reporter"

Please help me understand these sentences.

[image: Radio Reporter]

Comment: Why do you think they should have said "not TV reporter"?

Comment: @CowperKettle Some languages, e.g. French, do not put articles before professions after the copula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The indefinite article **a** derives from the word **one**.

> Do you work for the news?
>   Yes, I'm **a** reporter.

There are many news reporters in the world, and I am **one** of them. You are simply describing your job. I'm a reporter; I'm a baker, I'm an English teacher.

The same goes for "I am not a TV reporter": my job is not one of a TV reporter. I am a reporter, yes, but not a TV reporter.

The adjective "TV" does not make the noun "reporter" definite, just as the adjective "red" does not make the noun "ball" definite here:

> This is **a** ball. This is not **a** red ball.

---

Sometimes, if the position or function is unique, [we omit the indefinite article](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56365/omission-of-the-in-elected-him-president-and-made-captain):

> They elected me President of Russia.
>   They made me Captain of the team.

This does not work in the Scott/Heather example. A news company might have dozens of TV reporters, so it's not a unique role. Even if it has one reporter at this particular point in time, it might hire several new reporters tomorrow, and they will all work together. A country is unlikely to have several presidents at once.

---

Had the definite article been used, it might've implied that there's only one reporter in your news company. Here's an example:

> Do you work for Moscow News?
>   Yes, I'm **the** reporter.
>   Gee, that must be a very small company! Only one reporter!

In another situation, the use  of the definite article might imply that some particular reporter is being discussed, a reporter the first person knows about:

> Do you work for Moscow News?
>   Yes, I'm **the** reporter you heard yesterday in the evening program about Maslenitsa celebrations.

I'm **that** particular reporter (whom you heard yesterday when you tuned in to Moscow News on the radio)

---

The situation gets interesting if both Heather and Scott know that there's only two reporters in a small news company: one TV reporter, one radio reporter.

> 1. Scott: Do you work at Los Gatos News? I know they have a couple of reporters: a TV and a radio reporter.
> 2. Heather: Yes, I do. I'm a reporter there.
> 3. Scott: Where's the camera?
> 4. Heather: Oh, I'm not a TV reporter. I'm a radio reporter.
> 5. Scott: Oh.

Here, Heather can use **a** on line 4. But she can use **the** on line 4 either:

> 4. Heather: Oh, I'm not the TV reporter. I'm the radio reporter.

If she uses **the**, then she implies "I'm not that sole TV reporter at Los Gatos News. I'm that sole radio reporter there". If she uses **a**, then she merely describes the type of her job.